# Why docker build with --squash create intermidiate image

Tags: docker

I know that `--squash` flag is not always recomended for `docker build` command, but I want to understand the behaviour of this flag.

I created a docker image (in this example it was based on NVIDIA parent image) with the following command:

```
docker build -t nvidia .
```

The `docker images` showed the following:

```
REPOSITORY     TAG       IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
nvidia         latest    b956431d1f05        6 seconds ago       9.31GB
```

After that I created with the same Dockerfile another image with --squash:

```
docker build --squash -t nvidia-squash .
```

Now the `docker images` show the following:

```
REPOSITORY     TAG       IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
nvidia-squash  latest    d7b3968277d4        4 seconds ago       9.31GB
<none>         <none>    66154f6a6cd4        4 seconds ago       9.31GB
nvidia         latest    b956431d1f05        7 minutes ago       9.31GB
```

We can see that the squash option cause an intermediate image to be built.

Why?

Comment: `squash` still builds an image the normal way; it just generates a squashed version after. It would be much harder to QA completely dedicated codepaths for such a rarely-used option to do otherwise, and there's potential for those codepaths to break assumptions in other parts of the software stack; it's much saner from a software-quality perspective to have only one way to do things, and leave the munging for the output end..

Comment: First, thank you very much for your answer, it really help me to understand this topic. Secondly, it is not that I not happy with this, this understanding help me to do the correct decision instead of to do mistake and ask for fix here, so I can see a lot of value to such questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation is explicit](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/); bolding added for emphasis:

> **Once the image is built**, squash the new layers into a new image with a single new layer.

Thus, squash doesn't change how the image is built; it only adds a new step *after* that build is complete. Moreover, the documentation *also* explicitly covers that intermediate layers are still created and stored in the build cache; from the KNOWN LIMITATIONS section:

> When using this option you may see significantly more space used due to storing two copies of the image, **one for the build cache with all the cache layers intact**, and one for the squashed version.